# Unpack error with tuple of tuples?

Tags: python, syntax, tuples

I want to iterate over the elements ((a,b),(x,y)) so I tried:

```
def method(tuple):
    ((a,b),(x,y))= tuple
    for element in tuple:
    .....
```

But then I read another stackoverflow page which suggested something like this:

```
def method(tuple):
    ((a,b),(x,y))= tuple
    for element in tuple[0:4]:
    .....
```

Both resulted in the error: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack.

Is this action not allowed in python, or do I just have a syntax problem?
I have checked the python docs as well.

Thanks for any advice.

Edit

```
map = ((1,0),(3,2))
    def count(map):
        ((a,b),(x,y))= tuple
        inc=0
        for element in tuple:
            inc+=1
```

Comment: Please show us your actual code and the data you used.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. After you unpack the tuple, why do you need to iterate? HOWEVER I don't think that's your problem. The error "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack." indicates that the tuple doesn't have form you expect. It's trying to break it up but failing. I'd make sure the data's actually coming in the form you're expecting (a log statement?)

Comment: I want to access each element to see if I could count how many elements there were in the tuple. But you're right. I tried shifting some breakpoints around and running the debugger and found that map was not in the form I thought it was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a tuple of tuples, of the form `((a, b), (x, y))`, you can iterate over its elements:

```
def method(tuples):
    for tup in tuples:
        for e in tup:
            print e
```

If you want to have 4 variables, you can use them separately:

```
def method(tuples):
    (a, b), (x, y) = tuples
    print a, b, x, y
```

**Note:**
Don't use Python built-in names as name of variables. In other words, don't use `tuple`as a name of a variable because it's a *type* in Python. Use something else, like `tuples`, `my_tuple`, ...